# Need help explaining Bayesian p-value plot

Tags: bayesian, p-value, pymc

I'm working through Chapter 2 of [BMCP](https://bayesiancomputationbook.com/markdown/chp_02.html) and am having trouble understanding why the plot of a Bayesian p-value looks so unexpectedly "spiky" or multimodal. Here's my code

```
np.random.seed(1337)

# Observations are 20 draws from a biased coin-flip
Y = stats.bernoulli(0.7).rvs(20)

# Model the observations as a vanilla Bernoulli RV
with pm.Model() as model:
    θ = pm.Beta("θ", alpha=1, beta=1)
    y_obs = pm.Binomial("y_obs", n=1, p=θ, observed=Y)
    trace = pm.sample(1000, return_inferencedata=True)
    posterior_predictive = pm.sample_posterior_predictive(trace)

# Plot Bayesian p-values
az.plot_bpv(posterior_predictive, kind='p_value')
```

And here's the output:

[image: bayesian p-value weirdness]

Any pointers or links most appreciated.

Comment: The `y_obs` in your model is a discrete outcome.  You're visualizing it as if it were continuous.

Comment: I've been reading more about this after posting. The underlying issue is that I have a poor mental model of how BPVs are actually estimated. I don't have a copy of Gelman's book, but this paper has been helpful: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/A6n41.pdf